# Want to implement this type(posted image) of side menu in swift ios

Tags: swift, iphone, navigation-drawer, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

Want to implement this type(bellow image link provided) of  side menu/ drawer menu  in swift ios  [https://dribbble.com/shots/5405926-Navigation-drawer-design-Dbotica-Healthcare/attachments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZHzc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try `AKSideMenu` or `InteractiveSideMenu`

https://github.com/dogo/AKSideMenu

https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu

Comment: Thank you Shivam Parmar

Comment: its my pleasure  make it right mark if its useful for you ....